# How to practically generate longitudinal waves in a plasma

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics, antennas, x-rays, microwaves

It can be read almost everywhere that plasma is the best convertor of transverse waves to longitudinal waves.
I'm not much interested in the theory here. Rather, I would like to know how to do it in a practical way.

So, assume I have a big plasma tube, and a 1GHz - 10GHz horn antenna. Assume furthermore, if necessary, that I can tune the ionic current, the gaz pressure etc.

**My overall question is:** how should I direct the horn antenna in order to obtain a longitudinal wave along the tube, and what other preparations should I perform?

**My secondary question is:** how could I check that I have created a longitudinal wave?
If I try to put an antenna at the other extremity of the tube for receiving the wave, then how can I be sure I'm not receiving usual transverse waves. In other words, what kind of apparatus is supposed to capture longitudinal waves, but not transverse waves?

Comment: What is the plasma frequency? Transverse waves can only exist above it. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmawelle#Plasma_ohne_Magnetfeld

Some theoretical knowledge of plasmas is required to answer your many questions. Why are you not interested?

Comment: my2cts. I'm also interested in the theoretical knowledge necessary to answer the question. I just meant that I expect practical details, and not only a long theoretical page of calculus. Regarding the plasma frequency, please assume what pleases to you if that can help to provide an example. Also, if this is a crucial point, what parameters should I tune to obtain a given plasma frequency.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation.

Comment: @my2cts - No, you can have transverse waves well below the plasma frequency (e.g., ion cyclotron waves, whistler mode waves, etc. if they propagate parallel to the quasi-static magnetic field).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Correct but I assumed no permanent magnetic field. The OP does not mention that he has access to a cyclotron ;-). See the excellent German language wikipedia article.